# Kivy: how to set checkbox to checked on start up

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

How can I set the status of the checkbox with the id set to blue to be checked on start up. I use python 3.6 and Kivy 1.9.2.dev0. 
I thought the lines `blue = ObjectProperty(True)` in `.py` and `value: root.blue` in `.kv`  would do that but apparently I am misunderstanding how `ObjectProperty` works

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window

class SampBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    # For radio buttons
    blue = ObjectProperty(True)
    red = ObjectProperty(False)

class SimpleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        return SampBoxLayout()

sample_app = SimpleApp()
sample_app.run()
```

The .kv:

```
#: import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox


<SampBoxLayout>
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint_x: .55
        Label:
            text: "Favorite Color:"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint_x: .265
        Label:
            text: "Blue"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint_x: .15
        CheckBox:
            group: "fav_color"
            id : blue
            value: root.blue
            size_hint_x: .05
        Label:
            text: "Red"
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint_x: .15
        CheckBox:
            group: "fav_color"
            value: root.red
            size_hint_x: .05
```

Edit: why use `value` and not `active`?

```
def on_checkbox_active(checkbox, value):
    if value:
        print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is active')
    else:
        print('The checkbox', checkbox, 'is inactive')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you did not misunderstand it. You just used the wrong attribute name.
Set the active attribute instead of value:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


root = Builder.load_string('''

<MyWidget>:
    CheckBox:
        id: blue
        active: root.blue
    CheckBox:
        id: red
        active: root.red
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    blue = ObjectProperty(True)
    red = ObjectProperty(False)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But then what does the `blue = ObjectProperty(True)`  and `value: root.blue` do? The code in the question is a simplification of the tuto http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/10/kivy-tutorial-5

Comment: @Enora you are wellcome :)

Comment: One last question for today. I understand the attribute `active`thanks to the kivy doc but not the `value` one. In the code at the top of the doc (cf edit in my question), they check the value of the `value` attribute with an `if` to print different statement according to the state of the checkbox. But, to my understanding, the state of the checkbox is set by `active` not `value`. So why use `value`?  I guess, it's the attribute used to communicate between .kv and .py but then why did [Derek Banas](http://www.newthinktank.com/2016/10/kivy-tutorial-5/) used `value: root.red` in his code?

Comment: @Enora I just answer it here :) aparantly if you bind on active from python, you get the value of the checkboxes active. If you want that in the answer I provided, you just `print(instance.active)` in the method `on_checkbox_active(self, instance)`. So in the link you provided, `value` is basically the attribute `active` passed to that function. Value is just a name of the parameter. You could call it banana if you wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136871/discussion-between-el3phanten-and-enora).